# From Angular-DjangoFramework-Docker-nginx to AWS

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, django-rest-framework

I have an Angular front-end app served by a backend app developed using django-rest-framework. The backend run on a docker container (manage with docker-compose) and is exposed to the world using nginx.

I want to move both apps to AWS but I do not have idea how to do it. Could someone expert in this give me the steps I need to follow to get my font-end and back-end ready for deployment with AWS.

Can anyone suggest some good tutorials, online courses or clear documentation that can help me to achieve it?

Thank you for your help